# How can I select an element's parent row in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
$("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
        $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
            $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
        });
        $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
    });
```

When a user clicks on a td element in a table it adds the row_selected class to the row. However when a user clicks on an input element inside of a td then it adds the row_selected
class to the td.

Is there a way that I can change event.target.parentNode so that instead of the parent
it adds the class to the parent tr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your handler to use jQuery's event delegation instead of your own...

```
$("#example tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event) {
```

...then you can just use `this`...

```
$(this).addClass('row_selected');
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(event.target).closest('tr').addClass('row_selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *parentsUntil()* function, that is sort of like finding ancestors. I cant remember the function for ancestors, but this will work:

```
$(event.target).parentsUntil("tr").addClass('row_selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(event.target).closest('tr').addClass('row_selected');
```

Instead of your line

```
$(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
```

Using closest(), you will be able to apply `row_selected` class to nearest `tr` element of the element you click, that may be a `td` or any other element inside it.